# How to get source code for all build-depends using cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I generated a new project using Yesod and am trying to go through the source to see how the pieces fit together. I am still a bit unfamiliar with most of the types so I have to keep a browser open where I hoogle/hayoo for types of things.

When I use Intellij for Java development I can usually just jump in to the source code of most of my dependencies. I wanted to try to replicate this for Haskell.

Since I am using vim for Haskell I thought I would just get the source for everything listed in build-depends and then generate a specific cabal_tags file and add that to vim's tags option.

My cabal skills are very rudimentary though. I noticed there is `cabal get` which can get the source for a package but it seems you need to explicitly specify the package and there doesn't seem to be an option for getting everything specified under build-depends in the .cabal file.

Comment: I don’t there is one, but you can get the list of packages using a combination of `cabal sandbox init` and `cabal install --dry-run` and some mangling of the output.

Comment: I don't know if this is due to a cabal bug but:
I tried `cabal install --dry-run` which only lists the top level yesod project name
Retrying with `cabal install --dry-run --dependencies-only` gives blaha everything is installed, use --reinstall
Retrying with `cabal install --dry-run --dependencies-only --reinstall` gives me the same please use --reinstall message.

Comment: Which version of cabal ? I can get list of dependencies with `cabal install --dependencies-only --dry-run` in an sandboxed environment. When you install a package with cabal, unless enabled with `hyperlink-source` option (Cabal 1.20+), module sources are not installed. You can fetch each with `cabal get`, unpack from a cache at `.cabal/packages/<repo>` or upgrade cabal and use above option. If using haskell-mode for Vim, update `g:haddock_docdir` setting with alternate path(s).

Comment: @Sam: That’s what I meant with `cabal sandbox` – you need to run the command in an environment that has nothing installed.

Comment: cabal --version gives me `cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.0 of the Cabal library`

Comment: Wait, I need to manually create a new sandbox and re-run the command, cabal won't allow me to just treat the current dependencies as if they didn't exist?